# Colored Normal Map

Tags: normals, baking, normal-map

Blender noob here! I've been trying to bake the normals from my high poly mesh to low poly mesh for hours and keep getting a weirdly colored normal map with a black background. I can't figure out why it's not the shades of purple like a proper normal map. I'm using a cage if that helps. [image]

Comment: A "shades of purple" normal map is a tangent space normal map, but you have your space, on the bake settings, set to object space.  Change that to tangent if you want the purple.

Comment: Maybe you have flipped normals? You can share your file if you want us to try: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Changing to tangent fixed it, thank you!

Comment: New problem though: it seems like the bake just doesn't actually run anymore. It says it's done, but just results in a flat purple map with no detail. Any thoughts?